# Pointer arithmetic and casting

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

```
short x = 5;        
short*ptr = &x;     
short *ptr2 = ptr+5; 

cout << ptr2 - ptr << endl;
cout << (long) ptr2 - (long)ptr << endl;
```

I understand that pointers store addresses, but I don't understand why the answer for both lines isn't 10.

Isn't ptr2 = address of pointer + sizeof(short) * 5?

Comment: Curious how you understand that `ptr+5` works in terms of the number of elements rather than bytes, but are surprised that `ptr2 - ptr` does, too. Would it not have been more surprising if `(ptr + N) - ptr` weren't equal to `N`?

Comment: Yes, I did think about it that way but I thought there was a better explanation than that.

Comment: note that the result of the last calculation is not guaranteed to be 10; the result of casting pointers to `long` doesn't have to be anything sensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is expressed in terms of elements of the type that is being pointed at.

`ptr+5` increments `ptr` by `5 * sizeof(short)` bytes.

The result of `ptr2 - ptr` is 5, because the compiler knows that `ptr` and `ptr2` are pointing at `short` elements, and so it divides the difference of the two memory addresses by `sizeof(short)`.  The number of `short` elements between those 2 memory addresses is 5.

Whereas `(long) ptr2 - (long)ptr` is not pointer arithmetic, it is just plain ordinary integer arithmetic.  It calculates the difference of the 2 memory addresses as-is, without regard to what they are pointing at.  Since there are 5 `short` elements between the 2 memory addresses , and `sizeof(short)` is clearly 2 bytes in your case, the distance between the 2 memory addresses is 10 bytes.

Comment: The key is that you're *casting* two pointers as long integers and then performing subtraction. On the other hand, `ptr2 - ptr` must be aligned with the size of the element. You would not want ptr+1 to advance _one byte_. You'd want it to advance to the next _element_.

Comment: Oh, I see! So when I casted it to long, it's no longer pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

The *memory* addresses may be ten bytes apart but that's not how pointer addition/subtraction works. The values used are *scaled* based on the size of the data type so, for a two-byte `short`, values will be half of what you would expect from the actual memory addresses (if your data type was the one byte `char`, it would work as you seem to expect).

It's really no different to a `pointer + 4` addition which gives you the address of the fifth element in the array, *not* the address five bytes befond the pointer.

This is covered in the `[expr.add]` section of the standard (text from `C++17`):

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as `std::ptrdiff_t` in the `<cstddef>` header (21.2).
>
> If the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, elements `x[i]` and `x[j]` of the same array object `x`, the expression `P - Q` ***has the value `i − j`;*** otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

---

Of course, this is a moot point in your case anyway since, as per that quote, what your are doing is undefined behaviour. Pointer subtraction is not defined unless both pointers are within the same array (or one byte beyond said array).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic does behave algebraically.

if y = x + 5, then y - x = 5.  This is true if x and y are integers, or x and y are pointers to the same type.

Note that you can not do z = y + x with pointers.  z does NOT equal 2x + 5.  It does not even compile.  You cannot add two pointers, but you can take the difference between two pointers (and get the count of elements).